# QGIS heatmap showing attribute values instead of point density?

Tags: heatmap, qgis

I'm a relatively new QGIS user trying to make a heatmap that will show not the density of geographic points but rather the density of another attribute (production capacity) at each of those points.

Tutorials I found via Google and StackOverflow have referred users to a "Column" dropdown in the heatmap plugin, but it looks like the current version of QGIS (2.2.0-Valmiera) doesn't have that dropdown. (Is it conceivable that they deprecated the feature?)

I could create 1500 duplicates of each point to reflect capacity, but that seems terribly inefficient (plus, it would exceed Excel's row limit). I'd appreciate any other ideas as to how to put this thing together.

Edited to add: I've found the "Use weight from field" box, which I suspect should largely answer my question, but based on the min and max shown in the heatmap plugin, it's not pulling the right data. Is there a trick to using this tool?

Comment: the weight option should solve this, and are you aware of gis.stackexchange.com?

Answer (score 4):

Should anyone come across this question with similar concerns, the answer to my question (as detailed by a kind member of the GIS Stack Exchange community [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/97248/what-exactly-is-the-min-max-of-an-extent-qgis-heatmap-plugin)) was an interpolation raster, not a heatmap. Turns out I was using the wrong tool for the job!

Answer (score 1):

Please read  [how to build effective heat-maps](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/256/how-to-build-effective-heat-maps) ?

Since you are looking for Distributions of attribute values rather than Concentration of points the QGIS heatmap plugin is the wrong tool for the job since it only does concentration of points.

**Try Raster | Analysis | Grid (Interpolation) instead.**

Another solution could be to first generate a vector grid - could be a hex grid if you like it fancy - and then calculate e.g. the average wellbeing score for each cell and map that.